# iOS 5 remote notification when launching app from dashboard

Tags: notifications, ios5, payload

since iOS 5, notifications are no more intrusive as previous. This is nice, but it seems that users prefer to tap directly on app icon from the Dashboard instead of the (small) banner area or notification center.

In such case, my app cannot get payload from notifications.. Even the 'application didReceiveRemoteNotification' method is not able to get the notification.

Has anyone got the same issue? Do you have any advice?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The intention of the push payload is just to display something useful/informative to the user in the alert. **Not** to actually send data to your app.

So you will need your own web service to provide the data your app needs. Your app should refresh/sync to that service when it launches to get the data.

Example: Instagram. It can push notify you that someone commented on your photo. But it's not actually sending the comment data in the push to display in the app. The comment data is downloaded when you launch Instagram and attempt to view the comment.